# C# MQ Api How to fetch message without getting exception in case of empty queue

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I have to periodically check messages in a queue within Websphere MQ. I haven't found better approach rather than try getting a message and handle 2033 reason code (which is NO_MSG_AVAILABLE) like this:

```
try
{
    // ...
    inQueue.Get(message);
}
catch (MQException exception)
{
    if (exception.ReasonCode != 2033)
        throw;
}
```

Is there better way to get message from queue? I think that there might be some openOptions flag that I'm not aware of, that wouldn't throw exception when no message available, but return null instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three ways to avoid or reduce this polling mechanism.
Here they are in oder of elegance(the higher the better):

1. MQGET with wait interval UNLIMITED and MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
2. Get your application be triggered by MQServer
3. Callback function - new with MQ V7 on both sides

Comment: I can't quite figure out how to set up the most elegant solution properly. I've set queue open flags like this: `MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING`, and get message options like this: `var getOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions { WaitInterval = MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED, Options = MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING }`, but it still executes immediately with NO_MSG_AVAILABLE. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the `MQC.MQGMO_WAIT` flag on `MQGetMessageOptions.Options`. Change it this way:

```
getOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions {WaitInterval = MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED, Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING}
```

Please note that this would make the calling thread to be blocked till a message arrives at the queue or some connection exception occurs. MQ has another client called IBM Message Service Client (aka XMS .NET) that provides a JMS specification implementation in .NET. This has a nice little `Message Listener` which gets automatically invoked whenever a message arrives in a queue. Unlike in the above example, the calling thread will not be blocked when Message Listener is used.

More details on XMS .NET can be found [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/xms_cuselisnr_net.html#xms_cuselisnr_net). Samples are also shipped with MQ and for message listener sample, please refer "SampleAsyncConsumer.cs" source file.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this. I solved it by putting the Message initiator inside the loop:

```
_queueManager = new MQQueueManager(Queuemanager, _mqProperties);

MQQueue queue = _queueManager.AccessQueue(
    Queuename, 
    MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE);            

string xml = "";

while (queue.CurrentDepth > 0)
{
    MQMessage message = new MQMessage();                
    queue.Get(message);
    xml = message.ReadString(message.MessageLength);
    MsgQueue.Enqueue(xml);                    
    message.ClearMessage();                                
}
```

There must be something in the Message internally that errors when reusing it for another get.